# ROS Tracked Robot Gazebo Simulation

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-kinetic, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am quite new to ROS and currently making a track robot model for gazebo & rviz simulation.

I have finished making the meshes of my robot with wheels and managed to make a basic URDF file.
First Question. Now I am wondering how do I add the track model to the URDF file. Do I just make another mesh of the whole chain and add it just as I did with the wheels? (what will be the joint type and where do I position the joint?)
Second Question. If I did add the chain and simply fixed its position. How will the chain move such that it moves in relation to the wheels?
I have checked the following links but I am learning them step by step.

1. [track Robot Gazebo-ROS](https://answers.ros.org/question/249874/tracked-robot-gazebo-ros/)
2. [Problems in simulating a tracked vehicle and spawning the model](https://answers.ros.org/question/10410/simulating-a-track-driven-robot/)
3. [Track Robot Plugin](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/863/tracksdriveplugin)
4. [Parameters for a skid steering robot](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5476/parameters-for-a-skid-steeringsimulated-tracked-robot-use-of-the-fdir1-tag/)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299831/ros-tracked-robot-gazebo-simulation/) by [FerdeLance](https://answers.ros.org/users/36595/ferdelance/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2018-08-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now there is official support for tracked robots in Gazebo 9 and 11 using ODE. Check out https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/blob/gazebo11/worlds/tracked_vehicle_simple.world for usage example.

---

Originally posted by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) with karma: 1366 on 2020-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1